# aws elastic beanstalk to a run a different requirements.txt

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm migrating a Heroku project for Elastic Beanstalk and for few weeks I need to have it running parallel on both servers. The problem is that the `requirements.txt` on the root of the project has some libraries specific for some heroku plugins.

Is there a way to change elastic beanstalk to not run the `requirements.txt` in the root folder?

My idea is to create a `aws_requirements.txt` and run it thru `.ebextensions/` but now I'm still getting error because the Beanstalk tries to install the main `requirements.txt` as well.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a docker base environment where you will just need to add an extra dockerfile and dockerrun file, but you can control everything.

And another solution may be to have the aws-requirements on S3 and do a copy from your .ebextensions

And yet another solution is do handle this on your side, where you keep AWS-requirements and heroku-requirements and do the copy before the eb deploy or heroku deploy